# Is the query correct?

Tags: mysql

Assume we have a table called "Persons" and another table called "Product_Orders". We will give the table aliases of "p" and "po" respectively.

Now we want to list all the orders that "Ola Hansen" is responsible for.

We use the following SELECT statement:

```
SELECT po.OrderID, p.LastName, p.FirstName 
FROM Persons AS p, Product_Orders AS po 
WHERE p.LastName='Hansen' AND p.FirstName='Ola'
```

Im confused with the OrderID, becouse it is not compared to anything such like.

```
SELECT po.OrderID, p.LastName, p.FirstName 
FROM Persons AS p, Product_Orders AS po 
WHERE p.LastName='Hansen' AND p.FirstName='Ola'
  AND po.OrderID = p.OrderID.
```

Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, in your first query, each row from the first table is joined with each row from the second one. Which will result in a result for each order (ignoring whether or not the order belongs to Ola Hansen).

However, I doubt that your table Persons contains forreign keys to orders. A clause such as

```
SELECT po.OrderID, p.LastName, p.FirstName 
FROM Persons AS p, Product_Orders AS po 
WHERE p.LastName='Hansen' AND p.FirstName='Ola'
AND po.PersonID = p.PersonID
```

would be more sensible, assuming that each row in the Product_Orderds contains a forreign key to the Person that did the order.

Answer (score 5):

What is being demonstrated here is a *join*, however the website you are using is teaching you the outdated implicit join syntax (with a comma). I recommend against this syntax. Instead use the `JOIN` keyword.

I checked the site and found out what the original [example code](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp) was (your question doesn't make it clear):

```
SELECT po.OrderID, p.LastName, p.FirstName
FROM Persons AS p,
Product_Orders AS po
WHERE p.LastName='Hansen' AND p.FirstName='Ola'
```

They forgot to add the join condition!

I'd instead write it using a `JOIN` like this:

```
SELECT po.OrderID, p.LastName, p.FirstName
FROM Persons AS p
JOIN Product_Orders AS po
ON po.PersonId = p.Id
WHERE p.LastName = 'Hansen' AND p.FirstName = 'Ola'
```

Now you can clearly see that the `po.PersonId = p.Id` condition specifies the relationship between the two tables, and shows how they should be *joined*. One of the many advantages of using the `JOIN` keyword is that it is difficult to forget to write the join condition, and it's obvious when it's missing.

You should avoid using w3schools.com as a tutorial. The site contains many errors and bad practices.

Comment: but the logic is just not at all the right one... his problem is about  what to join, not how to. You don't have an orderid on a person table

Comment: The old join syntax gets really difficult to read in a complex query.

Comment: We don't know the table structure, but I would think the Product_Orders table would contain some sort of person id (let's call it `person_id`) to identify the person the order is associated with. The join condition should be something like `ON po.person_id = p.person_id`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT po.OrderID, p.LastName, p.FirstName 
FROM Persons AS p, Product_Orders AS po 
WHERE p.LastName='Hansen' AND p.FirstName='Ola'
  AND p.PersonID = po.PersonID
```

Comment: I could do that, but I just wanted to match his own syntax. I'm correcting the logic, not the syntax, because I don't want to comfuse him.